Issue with Oracle Macro-Function and JPA/Hibernate: Why Does It Trigger an Exception with Valid Values?
I'm working with Java Spring Boot, JPA, and Hibernate to execute an Oracle SQL function, and I've encountered an unexpected behavior. The function is designed to accept a parameter and return it. However, when I include a null check in the function, it triggers an exception even though I am passing valid values.
The original Oracle function:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_SCHEMA.MY_FUNCTION (
    P_PARAM NUMBER
) RETURN CLOB SQL_MACRO AS
    V_SQL CLOB;
BEGIN
    RETURN Q'{
        SELECT P_PARAM FROM DUAL
    }';
END;

This function works correctly and returns the parameter value (example 104) when called from a Spring Boot repository like this:
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM MY_SCHEMA.MY_FUNCTION(:param)", nativeQuery = true)
List<JSONObject> findDataByParam(Long param);

However, when I modify the function to include a null check:
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MY_SCHEMA.MY_FUNCTION (
    P_PARAM NUMBER
) RETURN CLOB SQL_MACRO AS
BEGIN
    IF P_PARAM IS NULL THEN
        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20001, 'Parameter is null');
    END IF;

    RETURN Q'{
        SELECT P_PARAM FROM DUAL
    }';
END;

The function throws an exception indicating that the parameter is null, even though I’m passing the same value (104). This happens despite the value not being null and should be handled correctly.
Questions

Could it be that JPA/Hibernate is not properly injecting the value into the Oracle SQL function, making it appear as null when it isn’t?
Is it possible that adding the IF statement in the SQL function is causing unexpected behavior when called from JPA/Hibernate?
Are there any special configurations or considerations I need to be aware of to ensure values are correctly injected into SQL functions when using JPA/Hibernate?

I would appreciate any guidance or advice on how to resolve this issue.

Your code appears to works fine in Oracle fiddle. Although, I cannot see why you are using a macro rather than just using a function.

It's NOT a function but a MACRO, which means "IF P_PARAM IS NULL THEN" is NOT evaluated when the macro is actually used but at compile time, ... at a time the parameter is not instantiated.

does it mean that in a macro-function like that can't use conditionals, loops, etc with parameters, if I want to invoke it from a repository with hibernate/jpa? is there any reason behind it?

Additionally, is there any way to change this behavior so that the macro's parameter initialization and conditionals are evaluated at runtime instead of at compile time? or do you know any other approach

A SQL MACRO returns a SQL fragment as a string in which the parameters of the macro are substituted at execution time by string replacement, everything you do outside of the returned string is executed only once at definition time, when parameters are yet undefined. If you need the behavior of a FUNCTION then define a FUNCTION not a MACRO. They are plenty of MACRO examples on LiveSQL and AskTOM Office hours Oracle sites.
